# Цикл с предусловием

Tags: python, математика

Ниже прикреплено условие задачи, но сделал только через цикл с постусловием. Как условие `abs(curr-prev) < eps:` записать циклом?

```
def task(eps):
    prev=1
    n=0
    while True:
        curr=prev*(n+1)/((2*n+1)*(2*n+2))
        if abs(curr-prev) < eps:
            return curr,n+1
        n+=1
        prev=curr
        
print(task(0.0001))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то вроде

```
curr = prev + 10*eps
while abs(curr-prev) > eps:
    prev=curr
    curr=prev*(n+1)/((2*n+1)*(2*n+2))
    n+=1
return curr,n+1
```

вас устроит?

Comment: Эээ. Только `prev=curr` надо в начало цикла поместить, а в вашем варианте цикл гарантированно закончится после первой же итерации ))

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо!